# example for semi-additive fact

Tags: data-warehouse

I'm trying to find real-time examples for semi-additive facts other than "date dimension" example.

i.e. measures can be summed up across all dimensions except time.

I'm looking for semi-additive fact example where measure cannot be summed up across dimension other than time.

Thanks in advance.

-Ash

Comment: What have you tried and what's not working. Please post some code. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The classical example is the end-of-day on-hold quantity. It is additive across product, across warehouse, across every other dimension except time.

Comment: Yes- but the question is to find an example which is semi additive, but not in relation to date/time.

Comment: Sorry, I did not read carefully enough

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Account Balance ... Store Stock ... anything that has a "count" associated with it is typically semi-additive.

After "Rich"s helpful comment, I'll add some examples from the literature of measures that may not be additive across dimensions other than time.

1. Christopher Adamson's book "Star Schema - The Complete Reference" quotes two examples on page 269 - (i) A sales_goal which can not be summed over sales plan versions; (ii) a budget_amount, which can not be summed across budget versions.
2. Lawrence Corr's book "Agile Data Warehouse Design" uses the example of an order_count - page 245 - which would cause double-counting over levels in the Product hierarchy.
3. Chapter 7 of Kimball Group's Data Warehouse Toolkit, 3rd Edition, discusses the issue of over-counting in some depth, in relation to budgetting.

You'll find links to these books on our data warehousing bookshelf, http://ajilius.com/bookshelf

Comment: The question is looking for semi additive measures where it cannot be summed up for some dimension other than date/time. Account balance and store stock are both date/time related.

Comment: Thank you Ron. I'm yet to buy those books n read, but your answer opens a window of star schema wisdom.

Answer (score 3):

You can aggregate department headcounts to give an organization total, but you cannot aggregate them over time, so the Sales department headcount for March 31 maybe 20 employees, and for April 30 the headcount maybe 23, but that does not mean that the total headcount at the end of April is 43

Answer (score 0):

1. Quantity on hand
2. End of the month balance
3. Inventory of a good
4. Number of employees
5. Insurance policies

refer: [https://community.pyramidanalytics.com/t/q5m1dp/calculating-semi-additive-measures-in-bi-office#:~:text=Semi%2Dadditive%20measures%20are%20values,add%20them%20up%20over%20time](https://community.pyramidanalytics.com/t/q5m1dp/calculating-semi-additive-measures-in-bi-office#:%7E:text=Semi%2Dadditive%20measures%20are%20values,add%20them%20up%20over%20time).